# Type 1 error adjustment in pairwise T-tests

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons

I'm really confused with whether we should be doing type1 error adjustment in pairwise t-tests or not. I would like to explain my situation and see whether the it's appropriate to do any adjustment.

I'm developing a classification system and have 6 different configurations for which I get six different accuracy measures. I perform bootstrap re-sampling (non-parametric) to calculate confidence intervals for those 6 different configurations.

This is followed by calculation of p-value. Now, I'm wondering whether I should be doing any sort of correction for pairwise comparisons among those 6 configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Type 1 error is a problem for interpreting p-values. Adjustments for multiple comparisons change the p-values, *not* the predicted values. If you are putting together a classification system, you do not care about the p-values for the predictors. All you care about is the predicted value—the classification. So it sounds like Type 1 error adjustments are not something you need to worry about.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for the reply. Probably I didn't explain my question properly. I'm not concerned about the class predicted. I'm more worried about the test statistic used to measure the accuracy of predicted classes. I would like to compare the accuracy-config1 vs accuracy-config2 ...so on, in a pairwise manner. I perform bootstrap sampling and perform t-test to obtain p-values, null hypothesis being difference of accuracy is zero.